# Dynamic picklist column in pageBlockTable

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, pageblocktable, selectlist

I have a Visualforce page for an Order form in my Salesforce instance. The form includes a pageBlockTable for the products (line items) being ordered. So there is a button to add another line item, and for each line item there is a static picklist to select the product. Based on the product you select, there may be a number of product options available. So the next column is a dynamic picklist that displays the options for the selected product.

This works fine when there is only one line item. However, when there is more than one line item, the options picklist no longer updates properly when the product is changed. Any idea why, or how to fix it?

```
<apex:pageBlockTable id="products" value="{!items}" var="item" columns="5">
            <apex:column title="Product" >
                <apex:facet name="header">Product</apex:facet>
                <apex:inputField value="{!item.Product__c}">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="products"/>
                </apex:inputField>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column title="Product Option">
                <apex:facet name="header">Product Option</apex:facet>
                <apex:inputField value="{!item.Product_Option__c}" rendered="{!IF(item.Product__c == 'Other (Enter as Product Option)', TRUE, FALSE)}"/>

                <apex:selectList id="ops" value="{!item.Product_Option__c}" size="1" rendered="{!IF(item.Product__c == 'Quik-Shield 106', TRUE, IF(item.Product__c == 'Quik-Shield 112', TRUE, IF(item.Product__c == 'Quik-Shield 125', TRUE, FALSE)))}">
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="W" itemLabel="W" rendered="{!IF(item.Product__c == 'Quik-Shield 106', TRUE, FALSE)}"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="F" itemLabel="F" rendered="{!IF(item.Product__c == 'Quik-Shield 112', TRUE, FALSE)}"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="F CCMC" itemLabel="F CCMC" rendered="{!IF(item.Product__c == 'Quik-Shield 112', TRUE, FALSE)}"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="LE" itemLabel="LE" rendered="{!IF(item.Product__c == 'Quik-Shield 112', TRUE, FALSE)}"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="LE CCMC" itemLabel="LE CCMC" rendered="{!IF(item.Product__c == 'Quik-Shield 112', TRUE, FALSE)}"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="XC" itemLabel="XC" rendered="{!IF(item.Product__c == 'Quik-Shield 112', TRUE, FALSE)}"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="XC CCMC" itemLabel="XC CCMC" rendered="{!IF(item.Product__c == 'Quik-Shield 112', TRUE, FALSE)}"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="2.5lb" itemLabel="2.5lb" rendered="{!IF(item.Product__c == 'Quik-Shield 125', TRUE, FALSE)}"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="2.8lb" itemLabel="2.8lb" rendered="{!IF(item.Product__c == 'Quik-Shield 125', TRUE, FALSE)}"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="3lb" itemLabel="3lb" rendered="{!IF(item.Product__c == 'Quik-Shield 125', TRUE, FALSE)}"/>

                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column title="Size">
                <apex:facet name="header">Size</apex:facet>
                <apex:inputField value="{!item.Size__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column title="Quantity">
                <apex:facet name="header">Quantity</apex:facet>
                <apex:inputField value="{!item.Quantity__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column title="Unit Price">
                <apex:facet name="header">Unit Price</apex:facet>
                <apex:inputField value="{!item.Unit_Price__c}"/>
            </apex:column>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: (1) is product__c a lookup field or a text field? (2) except on the first selectOption, all those IF statements are unnecessary; use a simple expression: `item.product__c = 'Quik-Shield 112'` which will return either true or false

Comment: Text field (picklist).